# ASP.NET not able to show page when AddRazorRuntimeCompilation is added

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

i have a ASP.NET website with .NET6, i update all my Nugget Package and now i can't show .cshtml file at runtime.

I have error in output :

> Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.CompilationFailedException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll

And when i try to show a page the page show :

> Metadata file could not be opened 'C:...\bin\Debug\net6.0-windows\krbcc64.dll' -- PE image doesn't contain managed metadata
> @page

> Metadata file could not be opened 'C:...\bin\Debug\net6.0-windows\krb5_64.dll' -- PE image doesn't contain managed metadata
> @page

> Metadata file could not be opened 'C:...\bin\Debug\net6.0-windows\k5sprt64.dll' -- PE image doesn't contain managed metadata
> @page

> Metadata file could not be opened 'C:...\bin\Debug\net6.0-windows\gssapi64.dll' --PE image doesn't contain managed metadata
> @page

> Metadata file could not be opened 'C:...\bin\Debug\net6.0-windows\comerr64.dll' -- PE image doesn't contain managed metadata

When i remove the line

```
 .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation()
```

it works fine but I don't have the hot reload on my cshtml file.

The error appeared last week.

Anyone have idea ?

Thank's !

Comment: Hi, Please share the exception with English language.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the mistake, i edit my message :D

Comment: Does your project contain non managed dlls? There is an issue in github with very similar symptoms as the ones you have: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/18699 ?

Comment: Hi, yes, but i try with a empty project and i got the same issue :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error has been solved in .NET 7.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).